# Excel simple formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I have a doubt in this formula.

```
=SUM(IF(F36=H36;SUM(1);SUM(0)); IF(F52=H52;SUM(1);SUM(0));IF(H68=F68;SUM(1);SUM(0)))
```

I want to add the statement if those cells (`F36, H36, F52`, etc...) have a value/are not empty (have an integer number including 0).

So basically if those cells have the same value of a number but are not empty I want to add/sum '1' to the value that they already got.

This was made in a Portuguese Excel but I translated it.

Thank you in advance,
Rui

Comment: `count(range) + sum(range)`?

Comment: aren't the arguments in `IF` separated by comma like `IF(a=b,1,0)`?

Comment: Replace your `;` with `,` between arguments of IF(), and SUM().  (i.e. all of them)

Comment: @Fabricator - yes, comma in IF().  Also works in SUM() when summing several non-contiguous cells, i.e. SUM(a1,d5,f6).  If contiguous (range), `:` is used.  i.e. SUM(A1:Z1)

Comment: The `,` don't work has to be `;`. If I want to `IF` 3 cells I must put `IF((Cell;Cell;Cell);True;False)`.

And this formula is working. I just want to make it work WHEN the cells are not empty/blank. Only when they have a value 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: @Rui - Hmmm.  You say `,` doesn't work, but `;` does as delimiters in `sum()` and `if()`?   I get errors when using that syntax.  I wonder if this is an Excel setting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
=IF(Cell.IsEmpty(F36);SUM(0);IF(F36=H36;1;0))
```

Comment: You should mark this as answered (just click the check to the left)

Comment: I did but I had to wait 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

From the context, I am assuming you want to place a 1 if the two cells are equal, and a 0 if not:

Replace:

```
=SUM(IF(F36=H36;SUM(1);SUM(0)); IF(F52=H52;SUM(1);SUM(0));IF(H68=F68;SUM(1);SUM(0)))
```

to...

```
=SUM(IF(F36=H36,1,0), IF(F52=H52,1,0), IF(H68=F68,1,0))
```

Note the `;` were replaced with `,`.  (No extra charge.)

***Edited to address comments:***

if this equation is in a1, and it tests b1/c1, b2/c2 abd b3/c3, then these images should reflect the results:

First image is of the placement of the equation:
[image]
***Results***
[image]
***And***
[image]

***If they do not*** reflect what you are asking for, please leave another comment.

***However***, note that the sum() function will always leave a value, even if it sums a collection of blank cells.  That is it will not leave a blank.

Comment: @Rui - Why? What exactly _are_ you trying to do?

Comment: @rykker - I'm trying to do exactly what you said. If the value in those 2 cells are equal then add 1. if not add 0. To this point I have figured it out. But I don't want Excel to add 1 if they're blank.

Like a football game. If draw (cell1=cell2) then add one, else add 0. But if the cells are blank Excel sees them as equal. I want to add only when cells are equal and not blank.

Comment: Just to clarify:  say this function resides in a1, and it tests cells b1/c1, b2/c2 and b3/c3.  Given these criteria, if b1=c1 AND b2=c2 AND b3=c3, then ***a1 would == 3***.  _BUT_ if only b1=c1, and the other two did not equal each other, then ***a1 would == 1***.  Is this accurate?

Comment: I figured it out how to use the `Cell.IsEmpty` (something like that) function.
Nevertheless I appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

For each of three pairs of cells to test whether either one of each pair is empty and whether the two cell if not empty are equal maybe something like this:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(F36))*NOT(ISBLANK(H36))*(F36=H36)+NOT(ISBLANK(F52))*NOT(ISBLANK(H52))*(F52=H52)+NOT(ISBLANK(F68))*NOT(ISBLANK(H68))*(F68=H68)
```

I think Cell.IsEmpty is not a standard Excel function and the solution offered by the OP is a long way from answering the OP's question (ie only tests for one of the pair being empty and only considers one of the three pairs).

The formula above works for text as well as numbers or integers, so may need adjustment to be less flexible if inputs must be restricted to integer values and zero only perhaps once the OP has provided the examples requested.

Comment: As I said this was made in a Portuguese Excel and I translated it as best as I could. I think is most likely your `ISBLANK`. I tried the `NOT` but I couldn't make it work. But I find your answer useful too. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i knew that it's `É.CÉl.VAZIA`... but i didn't knew that there was a Stack Overflow in other languages... Thanks